# How to code for DHT11, pH Sensor with i2c 16x2 LCD in Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, relay

I'm working on my college project on which I have to measure the temperature show it on 16x2 LCD and also to switch the cooling device according to the temperature, also I have to use pH Sensor and have to display its value on 16x2. Currently I'm using the code below for Temperature and switching, but it is not working properly. It shows the temperature on the screen but also some garbage value, and also not switching properly.

```c
 #include <Wire.h>
 #include <LCD.h>
 #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
 #include <dht.h>

 dht DHT;
 #define DHT11_PIN 7
 LiquidCrystal_I2C  lcd(0x27,2,1,0,4,5,6,7);
 const int ledPin = 6;

 void setup()
 {
  lcd.setBacklightPin(3,POSITIVE);
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int DigitalPin = 8; DigitalPin <= 8; DigitalPin++) {
   pinMode(DigitalPin, OUTPUT);
  }  

 }

 void loop()
 {
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  float temp=(DHT.temperature);
  float Hum=(DHT.humidity);
  lcd.print("Temp         C  ");
  lcd.setCursor(6,0);
  lcd.print(temp);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.println("Humid        %  ");
  lcd.setCursor(6,1);
  lcd.print(Hum);

  delay(1000);

  if (temp <= 29)
   digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  else if (temp>30)
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will divide my answer into two parts:

1. Hardware:

Please describe your hardware configuration in order to narrow down your problem: How are you switching the relay? Is it optically coupled? Are you using a transistor? If so, what type? Does your relay have reverse diode protection? (Do **not** connect your relay directly to an Arduino pin)

2. Code

2.1. This for-loop in your setup() is incorrect:

```
for (int DigitalPin = 8; DigitalPin <= 8; DigitalPin++) {
   pinMode(DigitalPin, OUTPUT);
}
```

You are indexing from 8 to 8, hence you don't need a for loop to declare a single pin as an output.

2.2. In general, you can assign your output pins to variables, or as a macro like you did for the DHT. Just be consistent. Additionally, your code needs general tidying up:

a . Start your code with all libraries calling

```
#include <Wire.h>    // The Wire.h library is already called by the LiquidCrystal_I2C library, so you don't need to call it if you use the I2C one
#include <LCD.h>    // You are using the LCD library...
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>    // but also the I2C lcd library. You don't need both.
#include <dht.h>    // Is this the latest version? Use Adafruit's
```

b. Try to group all your macros at the beginning. Declare pins or constants here:

```
// Using macros
#define DHT11_PIN 7
#define DigitalPin 8
#define DHT11_PIN 7
```

or using constants for pins. Choose one, not both:

```
// Group all your const int together, for the sake of clarity
const int DHT_PIN = 7;
const int DigitalPin = 8;
const int ledPin = 6;
```

c.  I believe this constructor is not correct for the library you chose. Check the example from [this](https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.ino) library (assuming it is the same, which I believe it is)

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C  lcd(0x27,2,1,0,4,5,6,7);
```

try with this constructor, instead:

```
// Set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
```

d. The `setup()` function needs some changes too:

```
 void setup()
 {
   // You don't seem to be using the serial library. However, if you use it, it is 
   // preferable to start it first.
  Serial.begin(9600);  

  // LCD configuration
  lcd.begin(16, 2);    // Always call the begin() method first
  lcd.setBacklightPin(3,POSITIVE);    // Then, use additional configuration methods.
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  lcd.clear();
  // Once again, please check if you are using the right library. 
  // It might be the cause of the garbage you see.
   
  // Initialize the type of pin
   pinMode(DigitalPin, OUTPUT);
    
 }
```

e. According to Adafruit's [library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino) (please see the examples), you are missing a Macro to declare the type of DHT sensor you are using:

#define DHTTYPE    DHT11

f. In your main loop() you are reading values with some strange parenthesis:

```
int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
float temp=(DHT.temperature);
float Hum=(DHT.humidity);
```

which, according to the latest library, should be:

```
// The latest library does not have this prototype: int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN); What is it for in your dht lib?
  
float temp = DHT.readTemperature(); // instead of: float temp=(DHT.temperature); --> which should be DHT.temperature(); in any case
float hum = DHT.readHumidity(); // instead of: float Hum=(DHT.humidity);
```

TL;DR: Share your hardware in order to assist you. Update your libraries, clean-up your code, and use the right methods from the latest libraries.

Comment: Thankyou so much @daniel-melendrez for guiding me in brief, it is very useful and very helpful information for noobs like me. 

I was using Arduino Uno r3, a 6v relay module for Arduino having its own driving transistor, DHT11, 16x2 display, i2C module. I will also have to add pH sensor in this micro project but i didn't have purchased it yet. Once it'll be in my hand I will add that also and maybe i will need your help then too. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou so much for your guidance, below is the working code for me:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#define DHTPIN 7 //digital pin for sensor

#define DHTTYPE DHT11      // DHT 11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);

void setup() 

{
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); //for configuring relay output
  lcd.begin(16, 2);  
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {

 delay(1000);
 float h = dht.readHumidity();
  
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) 

{
   lcd.print("NO CONNECTION");
    return;
}

//Hum code
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Hum:");
  lcd.print(h);
  lcd.print(" % ");
//Temp code
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Temp:");
  lcd.print(t);
  lcd.print(" C");


//To operate relay
{
if (t <= 26)
digitalWrite(8, LOW);
else if (t>27)
digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
}
  
}
```

Comment: Currently it is working for operation of relay with respect to temperature, i will add the pH sensor code after completing it and will surely post here.

Comment: Great to know that it worked fine for you. P.S. Sorry for commenting this late!